# Javascript Regex replace token content, included token

Tags: javascript, regex, jestjs

i'm trying to make this test work, but i'm not able to get the proper REGEX:

```
test.only("Should replace text in brackets by variables in data", () => {
  let text: string = "This is some [name] in a [entryDate]";
  const _data: RequestData = [{ name: "Test" }, { entryDate: "12/12/2022" }];

  _data.forEach((param) => {
    const key = Object.keys(param)[0];
    const pattern = new RegExp(/[\[\]']+/g);
    console.log(pattern);
    text = text.replace(pattern, param[key]);
  });
  expect(text).toContain("This is some Test in a 12/12/2022");
});
```

It's kinda self-explanatory but I need that

```
"This is some [name] in a [entryDate]"
```

to be

```
"This is some Test in a 12/12/2022"
```

my best try, at the moment, with the above regex is:

```
Expected substring: "This is some Test in a 12/12/2022"
Received string:    "This is some TestnameTest in a TestentryDateTest"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why use regex for this?

Comment: "You have a problem, and you think you can solve it with a regular expression. Now you have two problems." ;-) You can just use string interpolation.

Comment: Consider teaching instead of pointing. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the data first to a single, plain object, and then iterate the placeholders in the string:

```js
let text = "This is some [name] in a [entryDate]";
const _data = [{name: "Test"}, {entryDate: "12/12/2022"}];

const dict = Object.fromEntries(_data.flatMap(Object.entries));

text = text.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, (match, key) => dict[key] ?? match);

console.log(text);
```